# Python3 - Handling hyphenated words: combine and split

Tags: regex, python-3.x, replace, split, nlp

I want to handle hyphenated words. For example, I'd like to handle the word "well-known" in two different ways.

First, combine this word i.e. ("wellknown") and the second way is to split the word i.e. ("well","known").

The input would be: "well-known" and the expected output is:

```
--wellknown

--well

--known
```

But I can only parse each word individually, but not both at the same time. When I loop through my text file, and if I am looking for the hyphenated words, I combine them first.

Then after I've combined them, I don't know how to go back to the original word again and do the split operation. The following are short pieces from my code. (please let me know if you need to see more details)

```
for text in contents.split():   
   if not re.search(r'\d', text):               #remove numbers
      if text not in string.punctuation:        #remove punctuation
        if '-' in term:
           combine = text.replace("-", '')      #??problem parts (wellknown)
           separate = re.split(r'[^a-z]', text) #??problem parts (well, known)
```

I know the reason I cannot do both of the operation at the same time, because after I replaced the hyphenated word this word disappeared. Then I couldn't find the hyphenated word to do the split (in the code is "separate") operation. Does any one have any idea how to do it? Or how to fix the logic?

Comment: Something like this? https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1968#issuecomment-371684603

Comment: Do you have a larger sample input of `text`? And the expected output?

Comment: Think of tokens more as an object than strings, then you can create a token with multiple attributes

Comment: Are there any words with multiple hyphens? A little more of the input data would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not just use a tuple containing the separated words and the combined word.

split first then combine:

**Sample Code**

```
separate = text.split('-')
combined = ''.join(separate)
words = (combined, separate[0], separate[1])
```

**Output**

```
('wellknown', 'well', 'known')
```

Comment: If there are multiple hyphens in a word, you'll have to change the 3rd line of code. I think the first 2 lines are enough to answer the question.

Comment: Thank you guys for help!. Fortunately, my case only have one hyphens between words. But good to mention that @ keyur Potdar. And thanks @codekaizer

Answer (score 1):

Think of tokens more as an object than strings, then you can create a token with multiple attributes.

For example, we can use the `collections.namedtuple` container as a simple object to hold the token:

```
from collections import namedtuple

from nltk import word_tokenize

Token = namedtuple('Token', ['surface', 'splitup', 'combined'])

text = "This is a well-known example of a small-business grant of $123,456."

tokenized_text = []

for token in word_tokenize(text):
    if '-' in token:
        this_token = Token(token, tuple(token.split('-')),  token.replace('-', ''))
    else:
        this_token = Token(token, token, token)
    tokenized_text.append(this_token)
```

Then you can iterate through the `tokenized_text` as a list of the `Token` namedtuple, e.g. if we just need the list of surface strings:

```
for token in tokenized_text:
    print(token.surface)
    tokenized_text
```

[out]:

```
This
is
a
well-known
example
of
a
small-business
grant
of
$
123,456
.
```

If you need to access the combined tokens:

```
for token in tokenized_text:
    print(token.combined)
```

[out]:

```
This
is
a
wellknown
example
of
a
smallbusiness
grant
of
$
123,456
.
```

If you want to access the split up tokens, use the same loop but you'll see that you get a tuple instead of string, e.g.

```
for token in tokenized_text:
    print(token.splitup)
```

[out]:

```
This
is
a
('well', 'known')
example
of
a
('small', 'business')
grant
of
$
123,456
.
```

You can use a list comprehension to access the attributes of the `Token` namedtuples too, e.g.

```
>>> [token.splitup for token in tokenized_text]
['This', 'is', 'a', ('well', 'known'), 'example', 'of', 'a', ('small', 'business'), 'grant', 'of', '$', '123,456', '.']
```

To identify the tokens that have hyphen and have been split up, you could easily check for its type, e.g.

```
>>> [type(token.splitup) for token in tokenized_text]
[str, str, str, tuple, str, str, str, tuple, str, str, str, str, str]
```

Comment: Thank you @alvas for the long solution. It works separately but I just want to have both of them work together. But still appreciate for your answer! :)

Comment: It works together too. Treat tokens as objects not strings. An object can contain anything or any function you like it to have.

Comment: ok, i see what you trying to do.. I can just add elements to the list.